# Lookup for 2 clients with multiple similar entries

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

I have clients in (A) repeated several times and products in (B) repeated several times. I want to create a list that shows client has used "x" number of products and what those products are. The only list I can create shows the quantity of each product (ie client may have used product 5 times).
I have 710 clients and 1200 products...not all products are used by all clients
So below I want to show

```
A                   B
A1 Office Fitouts   EMB LHS Chest
A1 Office Fitouts   EMB LHS Chest
A1 Office Fitouts   EMB LHS Chest
A1 Office Fitouts   Misc Item
A1 Office Fitouts   JHMontana
A1 Office Fitouts   JHMontana
A1 Office Fitouts   JHPerkins
A1 Office Fitouts   JHPerkins
A1 Office Fitouts   JHPerkins
```

Across 5 columns as,

```
       A                B             C                D           E
A1 Office Fitouts    EMB LHS   Chest Misc Item     JH Montana  JH Perkins
```

Comment: I tried to make sense of the data through some markdown edit but may have unintentionally fouled it up. Where are your expected results intended to go?

Comment: I just want to create another table/list that shows per client (a) the products they use

Comment: cant you create a pivot table that will do all that?